# the value of the Fourier transform of $\phi$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Here's the problem: Let $0\leq a <b$. Suppose $\phi :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is even such that 
$$\phi (x) = \begin{cases}
  1 & 0\leq x\leq a \\
  \frac{x-b}{a-b} &a<x \leq b \\
  0 &x>b.
 \end{cases}$$
Show that $\widehat{\phi}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{2}{b-a} \frac{sin(\sigma \omega)sin(\tau \omega)}{\omega ^2} (\forall \omega \in \mathbb{R})$ where $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ and $\tau =\frac{1}{2}(b-a)$.
Note: Use the fact that $\phi$ is even to minimize computations.

Here's the start my solution:
$\widehat{\phi}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\int_{0}^{a}e^{-i\omega x}dx + \int_{a}^{b}(\frac{x-b}{a-b})e^{-i\omega x}dx+\int_{b}^{\infty}0 dx)$

And I'm stuck here. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\int (x-b)e^{-iw x}dx=\frac {e^{-iwx}} {-iw} (x-b)-\int \frac {e^{-iwx}} {-iw} dx$.

Comment: will i be able to get the final answer going through this?